# How to specify CPU cores to celery workers?

Tags: python, celery, airflow, task-queue

I am using [Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) and [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) with it. I want to specify a list of CPU cores to the celery worker and celery worker should ensure to allocate processes on that particular core(s) only.

I have gone through celery documentation ([here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/)) with additional focus on sections viz Concurrency, Optimizing and Workers Guide. However couldn't find the solution.

So, how can I ensure that celery assigns tasks to particular CPU cores only. I cannot use `taskset`. If its possible to bind each `ForkPoolWorker` and processes it spawns to a particular CPU core, then celery becomes the perfect solution for us. However, if celery manages group of cores, we are comfortable with that too. But we need to dedicate CPU cores for celery worker.

Comment: Might be possible with `os.sched_setaffinity`, you could call this when the worker is initialised https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sched_setaffinity

Comment: Thanks @IainShelvington. But I do it using `airflow worker` command so can't do this without changing the source code. However your suggestion helped me write a bash script to spawn the worker and set the affinity of each worker using `taskset`. All child processes inherit affinity mask from parent and this actually solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, Airflow (actually Celery) doesn't provide a easy way to do this.  So we solved the problem using few hacks with suggestion from @[Iain Shelvington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548562/iain-shelvington).

We placed a new row in **airflow.cfg** that gives us the cpu core numbers to which celery should run the processes it picks.

Then we grep the processes' id of all the celery `ForkPoolWorker`(s) and using `taskset` we set the affinity to the cores supplied.

We wrote a bash script **start_worker.sh** to start worker. Also, we limited the number of workers to 1 but increase the `worker_concurrency`

**$AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow.cfg** looks like this:

```
...
worker_concurrency = 36
# We added the following line
cores_available = 12,13,14,15...45,46,47
...
```

The pseudo code for **start_worker.sh** looks like this:

```
# start a worker in daemon mode
airflow worker -D
# get the list of cpu cores
CORES=$(grep "cores_available" | cut -d '=' -f 2)
# get the PID of celery ForkWorkers
PIDS=$(ps -eaf | grep celery.*ForkPoolWorker*)
# for every PID, use the core
for idx in len(workers_count); do
    taskset -c CORES[idx] PIDS[idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting
`worker_concurrency = # of cores`?

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#worker-concurrency

Comment: ```worker concurrency``` option tells celery to allow # number of processes to run at any point in time. However this doesn't limit the processes to run on particular cores. They can run on any core.

Answer (score 0):

This *almost always* a bad idea, unless you are on a fancy architecture like big.LITTLE and you want to make sure that, for an example, system scheduler does not run computationally expensive task (thread) on wrong core. Celery can't do it, but you can do it manually on Linux using `taskset`. If you set affinity of the Celery worker, then all worker processes will run on that particular core, which is a terrible idea, unless your concurrency is set to 1 (just one worker processes).

If you still think it is a good idea, and it solves your problem, then I would suggest you to try writing a [worker_process_init](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/signals.html#worker-process-init) handler that basically calls `os.sched_setaffinity` on the newly created worker process. Keep in mind that this handler needs to be fast.

Comment: Thanks a lot for update.  However in a HPC set up, many a times we don't want scheduler to intervene a running process so we often dedicate physical resources using commands like taskset.

Comment: How do you prevent OS from scheduling some of the internal, OS processes on that particular core?

Comment: Never thought of this. However, I think its possible to isolate cores from OS scheduler. 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326579/how-to-ensure-exclusive-cpu-availability-for-a-running-process